# WebSockets with multiple tabs/windows

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm seeing some strange behaviour when using websockets with Play 2.1.2 and multiple tabs/windows.

When there is one tab/window all works as expected.
However, if I open another tab/window to the same location, the first tab/window's socket connection is closed. (i.e. the in.onClose() callback is invoked for the first socket)
Basically, only the last opened tab/window now has an open socket connection.

Why is this? Am I doing/understanding something wrong or is this a bug?

Small sample project is here: https://github.com/donovanmuller/ws-multi-test

Comment: This shouldn't be the case - each Browser tab/window should be independent of the other. What browser are you using?

Comment: Perhaps test with other browsers also

Comment: Hi Christopher, I'm testing with Chrome 28.0.1500.71.

Comment: Haves tested with Firefox 22.0 with the same result. Just re-checked and it's even happening on windows from two different browsers. I.e. I load up Firefox and all is good. Then load up Chrome and Firefox socket is closed... Got a suspicion I'm doing something wrong, any idea what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have fixed itself :)
I updated to the latest 2.1.x release (2.1.5) so that might have something to do with it.

The example project above now behaves as expected.